# Apparent package bug/conflict

Tags: packages

Learning about hyphenation, I've encountered something curious.

When I code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\hyphenation{acro-nym}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3cm}
TUG is an acronym. It means \TeX\ Users Group.
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

I get, as expected: 
[image: Expected_result]

However, when I substitute `\hyphenation{acro-nym}` for `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`, my outcome remains the same. It's as if the package wasn't recognized. What's going on?

Might help: I'm currently using "MiKTeX 2.9", with "TeXnicCenter 1.0 Stable Release Candidate 1" as my editor in a Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.

Using `\listfiles`, I can only get an outcome if `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` is not written in the preamble. The `.log` for the code above follows:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.    

Underfull \hbox (badness 2103) in paragraph at lines 7--7
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 TUG is an acro-
 [] 

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 7.
[1 

]

*File List*
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
***********
```

Comment: This is 'works for me' with an up-to-date TeX Live: could you edit in your `.log` file?

Comment: I would, if I knew how to. Started learning TeX like 2 hours ago.

Comment: Running LaTeX should generate several files in the same folder as the `.tex` one: one should be a `.log` (you may need to turn on 'Show File Extensions' in Explorer to see this).

Comment: Another funny issue: when I code `\hyphenation{acro-nym}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` in the preamble, `\listfiles` doesn't work. No list of files is shown on the log. Then I delete `\hyphenation{acro-nym}` and with `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` alone it still doesn't work. But when I leave `\hyphenation{acro-nym}` alone, `\listfiles` works and it yields this: `*File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)`

Comment: It works here with an up-to-date **MiKTeX** as expected. When you add a line `\listfiles` in the beginning, what a version of `hyphenat` do you get? Here the according line from log is `hyphenat.sty 2009/09/02 v2.3c hyphenation utilities`. BTW You should update your TeXnicCenter installation. There were fixed some bugs, also related to co-operation with MiKTeX.

Comment: @Speravir: whatever the problem was, it vanished with the update of  TeXnicCenter as you suggested it might. Unfortunately, TeX.SE does not allow me to accept a comment as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see it with up-to-date TeXLive 2013

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\hyphenation{acro-nym}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3cm}
TUG is an acronym. It means \TeX\ Users Group.
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}

*File List*
article.cls 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
hyphenat.sty 2009/09/02 v2.3c hyphenation utilities
***********
```